# How to create a div with 2 columns for text and image icon?

Tags: html, css

There is the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $vacancy) { ?>
    <div class="vacancy">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/vacancy_icon.jpg" />
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo CHtml::link($vacancy['name'], array('vacancy/show', 'id'=>$vacancy->vacancy_id)); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="public_date">Public date: <?php echo $vacancy['date']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see, each "vacancy" contains 2 columns for text and one image. There are some styles:

```
.vacancy img {
    float:left;
    width: 50px
}

.vacancy .name {
    margin: 0;
    width: 50px;
}

.vacancy .info {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
```

I need that each vacancy is visible in the following order: icon, "name", "info", But now it looks like that:

[image]

How can I fix it?

UPDATES:

Now code is:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $vacancy) { ?>
    <div class="vacancy">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/vacancy_icon.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo CHtml::link($vacancy['name'], array('vacancy/show', 'id'=>$vacancy->vacancy_id)); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="public_date">Public date: <?php echo $vacancy['date']; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

CSS:

```
.vacancy {
    width: 100%;
}

.vacancy .img {
    float : left; 
    margin-left:10px; 
    display-inline:block;
}

.vacancy .name {
    float : left; 
    margin-left:10px; 
    display-inline:block;
}

.vacancy .info {
    float : left; 
    margin-left:10px; 
    display-inline:block;
}
```

[image]

ANSWER: Right styles:

```
.vacancy {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
  .icon {
        float : left; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        }    

  .name {
        float : left; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        }

  .info {
        float : left; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        }
```

But now there is the next trouble - how can I align text in .name and .info by vertically?

Comment: Use the property display:inline; instead of display-inline:block;

Comment: I updated my answer. Please go through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all on the same line.

```
  .vacancy { 
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    }

 .img {
        float : left; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        display:inline;}

  .name {
        float : left; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        display:inline;}

  .info {
        float : left; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        display:inline;}
```

Comment: You have to use display:inline; in .img / .name / .info

Comment: put the .vacancy width property to 100%.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28883/discussion-between-tom-pouce-and-user2218845)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php foreach ($data as $vacancy) { ?>
<ul><li>
<div class="vacancy">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/vacancy_icon.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <?php echo CHtml::link($vacancy['name'], array('vacancy/show', 'id'=>$vacancy->vacancy_id)); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="public_date">Public date: <?php echo $vacancy['date']; ?></div>
    </div>
</div></li></ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Change your CSS like this:

```
.vacancy .info {
float : left; 
margin-left:10px; 
display:inline;}

.vacancy .name {
float : left; 
margin-left:10px; 
display:inline;}


.vacancy .img {
float : left; 
margin-left:10px; 
display:inline;}
```

Comment: add your img link inside a separate <div class="img"> and change css to .vacancy .img {.....}.

Comment: as @Tom-pouce suggested use display:inline; instead of display-inline:block;

Comment: The problem because of for each loop . Please add <ul><li> after <?php foreach ($data as $vacancy) { ?> and close it as </li></ul> before <?php } ?> It works fine.